# Microsoft Acess - incompatibility between Windows 7/Office 2013 and Windows 10/Office 365

Tags: windows-10, office365, ms-access

We have a small MS Access database shared between staff in an office. Recently the company upgraded my computer to Windows 10 and Office 365. Now when I use the database, it sometimes causes it to fail for other users who are using Windows 7 and Office 2013. I didn't make any changes to the database structure or programming or anything.

When the other users try to open the database after I have used it, some of the symptoms they are seeing are: a small flickering window that appears when they first open it, having to click twice in a text box in a form to get the cursor to appear, and having the database crash (gives an error message and opens the VBA window) when trying an operation that involves VBA code.

Do you know what might be going on? Is this a known issue? Is there any good way to fix it (other than getting everyone on the same operating system or maybe splitting the database, which I don't really want to try)? (I tried reverting to a back-up of the database, which fixed the problem until I entered more data into one of the tables, then the problem came back again.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: That is why I originally posted to superuser, not stack exchange. I don't know why it was migrated from there

Comment: The flickering can be caused by Access is updating references. Regarding the other: Try to decompile and compact it after you used it: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "your.accdb" /decompile /compact`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. FWIW the command line decompile idea didn't seem to fix it, maybe we will have to split the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *really* should not have simultaneous users with different Windows/Office versions working on the same front-end.

Access only stores a single copy of compiled code, with references to at least its own libraries. This copy is only compatible with the same major version of Access.

If you have two different versions of Access working on the same file, the code will need to be recompiled constantly, causing delays, possible weird behaviour, and possible VB Project corruption.

Split the database, and make sure front-ends are not shared between different versions of any of the DLLs Access is referencing  (or, ideally, not shared at all). Different versions of Office is a common culprit, different Windows versions matter less often.

Answer (score 1):

Is you Access file using any other Office functionality (Word, Excel, Outlook)? If it does, when you open it in Office 365 it links to the references for the newer versions of these products breaking the references for anyone that has the older versions.

The only way around that is to split the database and have different front ends for each version of Access. They can still share the same data (back-end).

Splitting the database is not really complicated. Just make two copies of the database. On one (front end) delete all tables and queries and then link them from the other one (back end). You will have some redundancy that can be cleaned up later in your back end (for example all forms/reports can be deleted form the back end), but other than that is all there is.

Comment: The database does have Outlook functionality to generate emails so this might help explain the problem, thanks.